# El comando git reset afecta al repositorio remoto si no hago un push

Tags: git, gitlab, git-commit

Hice un `push` a la rama master. luego de eso seguí trabajando pero olvide hacer el `checkout` de nuevo a la rama de desarrollo. Cuando volví a la rama de desarrollo después de algunos días lo hice con un `checkout -f desarrollo`. para volver a la rama de desarrollo y hacer el push de los progresos en esa rama. El echo es que al hacer el `checkout` de master a desarrollo perdí el trabajo de esos días.
Pensé que quizá podría hacer un `git reset` y volver a el commit previo a moverme de rama, pero no se si esto afectara también a la rama master que esta funcionando en remoto donde no solo están mis progresos sino también el de otras personas ¿Hay alguna manera de recuperar lo perdido sin afectar la rama master en el repositorio remoto? Me preocupa que al revertir el commit también se borre el progreso del resto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entendí bien, tienes revisiones en la rama `master` **local** que hiciste por equivocación en esa rama y que te gustaría llevar más bien a la rama de desarrollo? Y colocando la rama `master` sobre la misma posición de la rama `master` **remota** al final? Si es así, no es complicado. Voy a asumir como ejemplo que el trabajo que quieres mover a la rama de desarrollo es de unos 6 commits en línea recta:

```
git checkout desarrollo
git cherry-pick master~6..master # aplicar las últimas 6 revisiones de master sobre donde estas parado
# ya tienes los cambios aplicados en desarrollo, como por arte de magia.
# ahora pongamos master donde está el master remoto
git branch -f master origin/master
```

Y con eso queda resuelto. Sigue tus flujos ordinarios para empujar a la rama de desarrollo.

Si lo quieres hacer con rebase::

```
git checkout --detach master
git rebase --onto desarrollo @~6 @
# con eso movimos las 6 revisiones a desarrollo
git branch -f desarrollo # colocar desarrollo donde estoy parado
git branch -f master origin/master
```

Sobre las preguntas de lo que pueda pasar en las ramas remotas al hacer operaciones locales: la única forma de afectar ramas remotas es haciendo `git push`, sin importar lo que hagas con tus ramas locales. Mientras no hagas un push, solo estás afectando cosas en tu repo local.

Comment: Muchas gracias!